# How to detect if a Java System property has changed?

Tags: java, properties, listener, jmx

I would like to know when a System property is changed. I have an application, in an application server, that somehow is changing a system property (`System.setProperty()` I think). I was taking a look and I have found different approaches:

1. [JPDA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410054/attach-to-another-jvm-and-listen-for-events-possible)
2. [Observer & Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130673/triggering-events-in-java-when-an-objects-state-changes)
3. [Property change listener?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)
4. [JMX?](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html)

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mentioned JMX.  Are you trying to detect the property from outside of your application?

Comment: You can try running with a security manager/policy that prohibits changes and see where the 'splosion happens.

Comment: Why do you need to know whether the System property is changed?  If you don't need a synchronous notification, why not just spawn a scheduled thread to check periodically?  (The simplest thing that could work?)

Comment: Thank you very much guys!Ok, I do not mind, the best would be to detect it from "outside" the app, but I think that I am allowed to add any hook (filter, listener...) to it. Yes, you are right, was my first attempt, but the configuration of the java policies is a little bit tough... I need it because it is changing the XML parser and it is screwing up my server. Yes I am also in run a thread for checking it, but what I would like the most is to find out who is changing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace the system Properties with your own custom subclass.

```
MyProperties newProps = new MyProperties(System.getProperties());
System.setProperties(newProps);
```

Then, just write a subclass of Properties which hooks the relevant methods.

Comment: Thank you jtahlborn! Yes I could, are you thinking in some kind of decorator (like the HttpServletRequestWrapper for the HttpServletRequest)? The thing is that the application should invoke my implementation...

Comment: @Gaucho - it doesn't really need to be decorator.  a simple subclass which overrides the methods you care about is all you need.  you just need to copy the existing system properties into your impl.

Comment: mmm, interesting, and how I can make that the application invokes my implementation instead the default one? Thanks!

Comment: jtahlborn, you rock! That's right I have just implemented a simple class that extends java.util.Properties and overrides the setProperty(String, String). If the application tries to set a "forbidden" property I throws a RunTimeException. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you primarily want to find the issue, I would look at using the [`SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) for this.  It has a couple methods available [`checkPropertiesAccess()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkPropertiesAccess%28%29) and [`checkPropertyAccess()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkPropertyAccess%28java.lang.String%29) which look like they will help you to ***find*** the issue, but not necessarily be able to 'notify you when a system property has changed.'

Comment: Thank you Nicholas! Yes, that was my first attempt:  try {securityManager.checkPermission(new PropertyPermission("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory","write"));} catch (SecurityException securityException) {.../... But you need to create a security manager first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624468/deny-jvm-system-property-write